# What makes this question a good one?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72485/in-klinget-gl%c3%b6ckchen-klinget-is-klinget-the-imperative-form) has two upvotes at the time of writing and two answers.
However in my eyes this is a question that can easily be answered by a conjugation table and as such is not a good fit for this site.

What am I missing here? When do "we" deviate from this policy?

Comment: Voting behavior is the business of the users. I don't think it makes sense to discuss the quality of individual posts here. The users who upvoted this question might not even see this post.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach it's not about the voting behaviours of others. In my eyes the question is in clear violation of what is acceptible on this site but somehow it isn't. So I'm asking why it is not in order to get another pov on this.

Comment: I feel I don't fully understand your question: On the one hand your write "it is not about the voting behaviors of others". On the other hand your question would not make sense if the question had no upvotes. The question you ask - "When do we deviate from this policy?" makes no sense to me - there is no policy for up- or downvoting questions. Do you think the question is bad? Downvote. Do you think the question is off-topic? Mark it as off-topic. Do you want to draw attention in order to collect more off-topic votes?

Comment: Just a sidenote: I don't think the question can be answered with a conjugation table. Morphologically, _klinget_ can both be the imperative and the present indicative form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:klingen) *klinget* appears at exactly one position, in present tense, conjunctive, second person plural. It is not self-evident, how this covers the requesting quality stated in the example text.

Given that there is also the complication of an old text, additionally requiring meter, the number of possible complications increases far beyond *can be answered by a conjugation table* level.

I find some of the questions citing *Zauberflöte* libretto as unlikely to be useful for another future visitor, but this question has a valid point.